# winrmsrv Virus, Windows Security all gone

Tags: windows-10, security, virus, windows-defender

I have been hit with a Virus that disables Windows Security by removing all its components (Windows 10). Startup Repair fails to run and I don't have a system restore that dates back before this (or even the virus somehow survives system restores not sure). The virus also disguises as the `winrmsrv` service and tries to get firewall access (I denied that).

[image: Windows Security Empty]

I've downloaded MalwareBytes and scanned for malwares, the threats were detected and removed but the security components are still missing. Previously, I've resorted to resetting the PC which fixed the issue but now it's back again (after around 6 months) and I can't find the source of it.

My initial thought is that the malware could be up within a removable flash drive (I got an infection previously within a drive but it was scanned and removed before opening anything within the drive). But upon further inspection, all other laptops within my home are not affected and we use the flash medias interchangeably so it must be still stuck somewhere within my PC.

The Defender Firewall appears to be running but can only be accessed from the start menu, and I get this message as well (screenshot below). In control panel, the firewall appears to be working.
[image: Microsoft Defender Firewall Issue]
[image: Defender Firewall from the Control Panel]

**My question is:** How it is coming back after a PC reset? Is there something that I'm missing or misunderstanding? In addition, can I fix missing components in Windows without resorting to a factory reset?

Answer (score 0):

> (1) How it is coming back after a PC reset?
>
> (2) In addition, can I fix missing components in Windows without
> resorting to a factory reset?

(1) I assume you mean "how is a correct system coming back" .  Reset (Windows Repair or Factory Reset) re-writes Windows and can repair some type of viruses (not all).

(2) Windows Repair that keeps anything does not repair a damaged User Profile.  Only Keep Nothing or Factory Reset deletes a User Profile.

Accordingly - Given the extent of the damage, good advice here after an extensive virus is to back up your data, documents and email and then reinstall Windows fresh and restore your apps and data.

If you suspect a Root Kit virus, use TDSS Killer (Kaspersky) to scan for this before rebuilding.

Be very careful about spam emails and make sure you keep good backups.

Good luck with this.

Comment: Hi @John thanks for your answer. (1) No I mean how is the virus coming back after a reset? My flash drives are scanned and clean.

Comment: If you clean up your drive as I suggest, the viruses will not likely come back. Only a root kit virus can do that. Use TDSS Killer. I added this item to my answer

Comment: Ok, so TDSS Killer didn't catch anything so it should be an ordinary virus. I have 2 drives in my system, one for windows/apps and the other one (with 2 partitions) for files and stuff. Usually a virus infects both or the boot/system drive only?

Comment: That is a tough call.  Maybe fix up your main drive and if drive 2 is just data, Windows Defender will catch it.